# Two for loops for with some conditions

Tags: python, for-loop, tf-idf

I have two sets

```
tf_ar=[0.0,0.032,0.235,0.65,0,....]  and
idf=[1.2,1.6,0.68,....]
```

I have to do multiplication of idf and tf_ar so that each term in idf multiply to six terms in tf_ar. It implies that

```
(number of terms in tf_ar)= [6*(number of terms in idf)]
```

How should i need to give conditions for it so it will continue to loop for next six terms in tf_ar?

```
j=0
for term in idf:
    i=0
    for tf in tf_ar:
        if i==6:
            break
        else:
            tf_idf+=str(float(tf)* idf[j])+','

    i+=1
tf_idf=tf_idf.strip()+'\n'
j+=1
```

For Example:

```
tf_ar=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12...]
idf=[A,B,...]
```

I want result as

```
tf_idf=[1A,2A,3A,4A,5A,6A,7B,8B,9B,10B,11B,12B...]
```

I want idf should be multiplied by six terms of tf_ar and should continue with next terms.

Comment: Can you please show the expected output?

Comment: you loop increment i+=1 needs to be indented once more for starters ;) and I have a feeling your doing something weird with the letter "j"...as you only increment it after everything.

Comment: Ah, and for anyone who want sclarification, I think I understand what hes saying.
He wants to store in an array the results of: first number in idf times the first number in tf_ar, then first number in idf times the second number in tf_ar...etc.. until the second number in idf times the seventh number in tf_ar..continue the cycle.

Comment: I have edited the question for your better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might give you some ideas, though I'm sure it's not 100% correct for your specific use case because the code you posted is sort of unclear.  But you should be able to adapt this to your needs.

```
result = []
for ii, term in enumerate(idf):
    result.append(0)
        for tf in tf_ar[6*ii:6*(ii+1)]:
            result[-1] += term * tf
```

The key idea is to "enumerate" to get an integer index to go along with the iteration over `idf`, then make "slices" with [x:y] of `tf_ar` which are 6 wide each.

Answer (score 2):

it seems like something like this would do the trick for you:

```
[a * b for a in idf for b in tf_ar]
```